# Python: Naive Bayes fit function gives TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number

Tags: python, python-2.7

The below code of Python 2.7 is giving error:

```
beta=0.5

from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
nb = GaussianNB()
print "Y_Train data: ",y_train
print "X_Train data: ",X_train
nb.fit(X_train,y_train)

nb.fit(X_train,y_train)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<ipython-input-116-c1ccb2227816>", line 1, in <module>
nb.fit(X_train,y_train)
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\py27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\naive_bayes.py", line 
173, in fit
X, y = check_X_y(X, y)
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\py27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", 
line 510, in check_X_y
ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\py27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", 
line 393, in check_array
array = array.astype(np.float64)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number

print train.dtypes
```

id                                                int64

timestamp                                datetime64[ns]

full_sq                                         float64

product_type                                      int64

sub_area                                          int64

area_m                                          float64

raion_popul                                       int64

green_zone_part                                 float64

indust_part                                     float64

children_preschool                                int64

preschool_education_centers_raion                 int64

children_school                                   int64

school_education_centers_raion                    int64

school_education_centers_top_20_raion           float64

healthcare_centers_raion                          int64

university_top_20_raion                         float64

sport_objects_raion                             float64

additional_education_raion                      float64

culture_objects_top_25                            int64

culture_objects_top_25_raion                    float64

shopping_centers_raion                          float64

office_raion                                    float64

thermal_power_plant_raion                         int64

incineration_raion                                int64

oil_chemistry_raion                               int64

radiation_raion                                   int64

railroad_terminal_raion                           int64

big_market_raion                                  int64

nuclear_reactor_raion                             int64

detention_facility_raion                          int64

full_all                                        float64

male_f                                          float64

female_f                                        float64

young_all                                         int64

young_male                                        int64

young_female                                      int64

work_all                                          int64

work_male                                         int64

work_female                                       int64

ekder_all                                         int64

ekder_male                                        int64

ekder_female                                      int64

0_6_all                                           int64

0_6_male                                          int64

0_6_female                                        int64

7_14_all                                          int64

7_14_male                                         int64

7_14_female                                       int64

0_17_all                                          int64

0_17_male                                         int64

0_17_female                                       int64

16_29_all                                       float64

16_29_male                                      float64

16_29_female                                    float64

0_13_all                                          int64

0_13_male                                         int64

0_13_female                                       int64

ID_metro                                          int64

metro_min_avto                                  float64

metro_km_avto                                   float64

kindergarten_km                                 float64

school_km                                       float64

park_km                                         float64

green_zone_km                                   float64

industrial_km                                   float64

water_treatment_km                              float64

cemetery_km                                     float64

incineration_km                                 float64

railroad_station_avto_km                        float64

railroad_station_avto_min                       float64

ID_railroad_station_avto                          int64

public_transport_station_km                     float64

public_transport_station_min_walk               float64

water_km                                        float64

water_1line                                       int64

mkad_km                                         float64

ttk_km                                          float64

sadovoe_km                                      float64

bulvar_ring_km                                  float64

kremlin_km                                      float64

big_road1_km                                    float64

ID_big_road1                                      int64

big_road1_1line                                   int64

big_road2_km                                    float64

ID_big_road2                                      int64

railroad_km                                     float64

railroad_1line                                    int64

zd_vokzaly_avto_km                              float64

ID_railroad_terminal                              int64

bus_terminal_avto_km                            float64

ID_bus_terminal                                   int64

oil_chemistry_km                                float64

nuclear_reactor_km                              float64

radiation_km                                    float64

power_transmission_line_km                      float64

thermal_power_plant_km                          float64

ts_km                                           float64

big_market_km                                   float64

market_shop_km                                  float64

fitness_km                                      float64

swim_pool_km                                    float64

ice_rink_km                                     float64

stadium_km                                      float64

basketball_km                                   float64

hospice_morgue_km                               float64

detention_facility_km                           float64

public_healthcare_km                            float64

university_km                                   float64

workplaces_km                                   float64

shopping_centers_km                             float64

office_km                                       float64

additional_education_km                         float64

preschool_km                                    float64

big_church_km                                   float64

church_synagogue_km                             float64

mosque_km                                       float64

theater_km                                      float64

museum_km                                       float64

exhibition_km                                   float64

catering_km                                     float64

ecology                                           int64

green_part_500                                  float64

prom_part_500                                   float64

office_count_500                                float64

office_sqm_500                                  float64

trc_count_500                                   float64

trc_sqm_500                                     float64

cafe_count_500                                  float64

cafe_count_500_na_price                         float64

cafe_count_500_price_500                        float64

cafe_count_500_price_1000                       float64

cafe_count_500_price_1500                       float64

cafe_count_500_price_2500                       float64

cafe_count_500_price_4000                       float64

cafe_count_500_price_high                       float64

big_church_count_500                            float64

church_count_500                                float64

mosque_count_500                                float64

leisure_count_500                               float64

sport_count_500                                 float64

market_count_500                                float64

green_part_1000                                 float64

prom_part_1000                                  float64

office_count_1000                               float64

office_sqm_1000                                 float64

trc_count_1000                                  float64

trc_sqm_1000                                    float64

cafe_count_1000                                 float64

cafe_count_1000_na_price                        float64

cafe_count_1000_price_500                       float64

cafe_count_1000_price_1000                      float64

cafe_count_1000_price_1500                      float64

cafe_count_1000_price_2500                      float64

cafe_count_1000_price_4000                      float64

cafe_count_1000_price_high                      float64

big_church_count_1000                           float64

church_count_1000                               float64

mosque_count_1000                               float64

leisure_count_1000                              float64

sport_count_1000                                float64

market_count_1000                               float64

green_part_1500                                 float64

prom_part_1500                                  float64

office_count_1500                               float64

office_sqm_1500                                 float64

trc_count_1500                                  float64

trc_sqm_1500                                    float64

cafe_count_1500                                 float64

cafe_count_1500_na_price                        float64

cafe_count_1500_price_500                       float64

cafe_count_1500_price_1000                      float64

cafe_count_1500_price_1500                      float64

cafe_count_1500_price_2500                      float64

cafe_count_1500_price_4000                      float64

cafe_count_1500_price_high                      float64

big_church_count_1500                           float64

church_count_1500                               float64

mosque_count_1500                               float64

leisure_count_1500                              float64

sport_count_1500                                float64

market_count_1500                               float64

green_part_2000                                 float64

prom_part_2000                                  float64

office_count_2000                               float64

office_sqm_2000                                 float64

trc_count_2000                                  float64

trc_sqm_2000                                    float64

cafe_count_2000                                 float64

cafe_count_2000_na_price                        float64

cafe_count_2000_price_500                       float64

cafe_count_2000_price_1000                      float64

cafe_count_2000_price_1500                      float64

cafe_count_2000_price_2500                      float64

cafe_count_2000_price_4000                      float64

cafe_count_2000_price_high                      float64

big_church_count_2000                           float64

church_count_2000                               float64

mosque_count_2000                               float64

leisure_count_2000                              float64

sport_count_2000                                float64

market_count_2000                               float64

green_part_3000                                 float64

prom_part_3000                                  float64

office_count_3000                               float64

office_sqm_3000                                 float64

trc_count_3000                                  float64

trc_sqm_3000                                    float64

cafe_count_3000                                 float64

cafe_count_3000_na_price                        float64

cafe_count_3000_price_500                       float64

cafe_count_3000_price_1000                      float64

cafe_count_3000_price_1500                      float64

cafe_count_3000_price_2500                      float64

cafe_count_3000_price_4000                      float64

cafe_count_3000_price_high                      float64

big_church_count_3000                           float64

church_count_3000                               float64

mosque_count_3000                               float64

leisure_count_3000                              float64

sport_count_3000                                float64

market_count_3000                                 int64

green_part_5000                                 float64

office_count_5000                               float64

office_sqm_5000                                 float64

trc_count_5000                                    int64

trc_sqm_5000                                      int64

cafe_count_5000                                 float64

cafe_count_5000_na_price                        float64

cafe_count_5000_price_500                       float64

cafe_count_5000_price_1000                      float64

cafe_count_5000_price_1500                      float64

cafe_count_5000_price_2500                      float64

cafe_count_5000_price_4000                      float64

cafe_count_5000_price_high                      float64

big_church_count_5000                           float64

church_count_5000                               float64

mosque_count_5000                                 int64

leisure_count_5000                              float64

sport_count_5000                                  int64

market_count_5000                                 int64

price_doc                                       float64

the above are the columns with their datatypes.
Why do you think I am getting this error please?
Thanks in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out the issue Strange and Uncanny reason. the error message gives no clue about it.

The real reason for this error:

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

Is the presence of null values in the various columns and this has nothing to do with float() as the error says. 
So I cleaned the data removed all the NAs and then reran. The code has run perfectly fine without any changes. So if you face a similar error in the future on Python 2.7 then you must look at your base data it would surely have NAs or values which cannot be converted to float or numeric. Remove them and then the code will run perfectly fine.

Comment: Yes you are right null values can cause havoc as in your case they did. Good catch @Puneet Mathur